# Como editar itens no sqlite.net com xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android

Estou aprendendo a usar `sqlite.net` no `Xamarin`, mas na hora de editar um item não está funcionando, eu depurei o código e dei um `breakpoint` no `EditItens()` e vi que os valores passados ao `conexao.Query<Itens>` estão corretos, mas os recebidos na variável `Teste` abaixo continuam os mesmo de anteriormente, estou errando algo na hora de editar os valores no sqlite? Também pode ter algo errado no `GetItens()`, mas acho meio difícil porque ele funciona normalmente quando usado para pegar os valores e mostrar no `ListView` da `MainActivity`. Abaixo os métodos citados

```
string pasta = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
public List<Itens> GetItens()
    {
        try
        {
            var conexao = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(pasta, "Itens.db3"));
            return conexao.Table<Itens>().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

public bool EditItens(Itens itens)
    {
        try
        {
            var conexao = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(pasta, "Itens.db3"));
            conexao.Query<Itens>("UPDATE Itens set Nome=?,Preco=? Where Id=?", itens.Nome, itens.Preco, itens.Id);
            Teste = GetItens();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Se puderem me falar onde posso encontrar o `pasta, "Itens.db3"` pelo Explorador de arquivos do Windows, vai ajudar também porque posso verificar se o item realmente não está sendo editado.

Comment: Não consegui resolver, mas reescrevi outro projeto do zero e o erro não aconteceu, vou deixar o projeto aqui pra analisar futuramente pq ainda n entendi pq não ia, mas ao menos sei que "entendi" sqlite

Comment: Consegui resolver, o erro era no Id passado, eu já pegava o Id quando fazia o GetItens() (em outra parte do código), mas mesmo assim eu igualava de novo, acho que de algum jeito isso causou o erro, percebi isso quando comecei o outro projeto, agr estou com dois projetos bem parecidos e ambos funcionando. O bom é q fixei o conteúdo realmente

Answer (score 1):

Anderson, utilize isso na atualização dos dados:

```
var conexao = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(pasta, "Itens.db3"));
            conexao.Execute("UPDATE Itens set Nome=?,Preco=? Where Id=?", 
itens.Nome, itens.Preco, itens.Id);
```

Opcional e preferencialmente, já que você tem o objeto itens, use isso:

```
conexao.Update(itens);
```

Seu banco de dados vai estar localizado no smartphone, na pasta que foi definida em

```
var conexao = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(pasta, "Itens.db3"));
```

Comment: eu tentei esses modelos e também não deu certo, o pior é q tentei a mesma linha de código em um projeto menor e deu certo, apenas aqui não deu certo, eu atualizei a pergunta com o endereço da variável pasta, tem como me dizer onde fica aquilo? Se eu conseguir saber com certeza se está editando ou não pode facilitar a resolução

Comment: O GetItens() está retornando algum valor válido? Se esse mesmo trecho dá certo em outra aplicação, verifique as declarações anteriores das variáveis fora desse escopo, por exemplo, verifique se está sendo chamado o conexao.CreateTable<T>.

Comment: Sobre verificar a pasta, coloque um Console.WriteLine(path) na aplicação e verifique no output do seu Visual Studio. Você pode tentar acessar através de um client no celular se a pasta for visível, ou através da solução da resposta do Andy nesse outro post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-do-i-view-the-sqlite-database-on-an-android-device

Comment: o código q eu estou criando serve tanto para escrever, quanto editar e apagar, se eu adiciono algum Item ele atualiza normalmente, se eu apago ele atualiza normalmente, mas quando eu edito, mesmo não retornando exceção alguma, ele continua intacto, vou tentar pegar o mesmo código de editar e de pegar itens e simplificar pra ver se o erro continua, e sobre as pastas eu estou dando uma olhada nesse link q me mandou

Comment: vou reescrever meu projeto do zero pra ver se o erro continua

Comment: Como você está estudando xamarin ainda é válido reescrever o projeto pra "treinar", tente utilizar os métodos com objetos do SQLite, isso vai te ajudar quando precisar utilizar herança em repositórios genéricos.